# Using resx files in a NuGet Package

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, resx

I have a NuGet package that implements some UI elements some of which contain text.

I want the text that is displayed to be able to be overridden by projects that consume the package.

When all the source is in a single project I've done this by using resx files as its a fairly frictionless way to make these kinds of changes without having to change code, its not clear to me how this would work if the code is delivered via a NuGet package since there seems to be relatively tight coupling between the xml file and the code behind.

Is it possibly to have the structure and elements of a resx file defined by a NuGet package but overridable by a project that consumes the package?

Comment: Do have a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-localized-packages) documentation.